# PHP MongoDB getting data from a date range using dateFromString

Tags: php, mongodb, date

I have data stored in the following format in MongoDB:

```
[
  {
    meta: {
       id: 1
    },
    data: {
       date: "03/01/2020"
    }
  }
],
[
  {
    meta: {
      id: 1
    },
    data: {
      date: "12/19/2019"
    }
  }
]
```

And I want to use PHP to get all entries that are greater than or equal to the current date, and less than or equal to the current date plus 6 months.

To do that, my query looks like this:

```
$query = [ 
            'meta.id' => 1,
            '$expr' => [
                '$and' => [
                    [
                        '$gte' => 
                        [ 
                            ['$dateFromString' => ['dateString' => '$data.date']],
                            time()
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        '$lte' => 
                        [ 
                            ['$dateFromString' => ['dateString' => '$data.date']],
                            strtotime('+6 months')
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

With this query, I should get back the first entry, with a date of "03/01/2020", however I get back no results.

I've also tried using `'format'` in the `dateString` but it doesn't appear to be supported yet, as it gives me an error.

How can I get this query to work correctly?

Comment: does `time()` return a BSON timestamp, or the number of seconds since epoch as an integer?

Comment: @Joe it returns an integer. I'm assuming the follow up to this is that dateFromString converts it to a BSON timestamp, and I would need to create that in PHP?

Comment: When the datatype is different mongod sorts in order of the bson type byte, except for a few special cases of comparing int/double types.  In a top-level comparison $gte will always return false for differing types, inside an $expr expression, it should follow [Comparison/Sort Order](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#comparison-sort-order), which would make all dates greater than all numbers, so nothing will ever match the $lt part.

Comment: @Joe I apologize in advance if I'm understanding this incorrectly. So I basically can't use a $gte statement since strtotime returns a different type then `dateFromString`? And if so, what is the correct PHP type to use if I want to get data between two dates that are formatted in `"mm/dd/YYYY"`?

Comment: You could use the `UTCDateTime` class to convert to a date object on the client side, or the `$toDate` aggregation operator to convert ms since epoch to a date object in the pipeline.